# Solver for Go Programming Laguage

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, solver, network-flow

Has anyone used MIP solvers (open source or commercial) with Go language https://golang.org/? I am looking for a solver for simple linear MIPs for network flows and set cover types of problems.

Comment: It seems the Golang wrapper [Golp, can solve MIPs](https://github.com/draffensperger/golp) using LPSolve. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Would you see [this](https://github.com/lanl/clp) link?

Comment: At [Mosek](http://mosek.com)  we have an experimental Go interface. However, my Go expert says is better idea to solve optimization problems using an OptServer. I.e. you send the optimization problem to a separate process that does the actual optimization.